# Why does the Logistic Regression throws conversion error (valueerror)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using Logistic Regression for a company to find out the specific variables that lead to the churn using their customers' data.

Applying an analytic method and an evaluative method. Annotate the data showing both methods in the findings

```
x = dF.drop("Churn", axis=1)
y = dF["Churn"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Output:

```
    C:\Users\Rebecca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
      FutureWarning)

    ValueError                                
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-268-0c050c82a577> in <module>
    ----> 1 logmodel.fit(x_train, y_train)

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
     packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
      1530 
      1531         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 
    accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype, order="C",
    -> 1532                          accept_large_sparse=solver != 'liblinear')
       1533         check_classification_targets(y)
       1534         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    717                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    718                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
    --> 719                     estimator=estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
    --> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
    --> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Bank transfer (automatic)'
```

Comment: What are the contents of the dataframe `df`?

Comment: Variable 'Bank transfer (automatic)' is in string format, you should do label encoding.

Comment: @BhaskarDhariyal can you show how to do this?

Comment: @Yatin  customerID SeniorCitizen Partner Dependents tenure InternetService OnlineBackup Contract PaperlessBilling PaymentMethod ... TechSupport_No internet service TechSupport_Yes StreamingTV_No StreamingTV_No internet service StreamingTV_Yes StreamingMovies_No StreamingMovies_No internet service StreamingMovies_Yes Churn_No Churn_Yes

Comment: Please edit that into your question...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
dF['Bank transfer (automatic)'] =  le.fit_transform(dF['Bank transfer (automatic)'])
x = dF.drop("Churn", axis=1)
y = dF["Churn"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(x_train, y_train)
```